# password storeage and retrieval

Tags: javascript

when using password and id they would have to be stored in a file . not in the source code. how does one store and retrieve the pass codes. all i have seen is input boxes. are the files random access or other type files? One has to have a way to store and retrieve over a million pass and id's

Answer (score 0):

Typically the passwords are not stored at all.  Typically you would store a hash of the password in a database.  It would then be validated by hashing what the user enters and comparing the hash to the one in the database.